# Am I supposed to use foreign keys for these 3 tables which are connected?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 3 tables:

```
Table: Albums
Columns: Id, Name, Description, Author, Folderpath, Thumbnail, Upvotes, Downvotes

Table: AlbumsConnection
Columns: Id, AlbumId, AlbumImagesId

Table: AlbumImages
Columns: Id, InAlbum, Imagepath
```

So far I've been using these tables without actually using foreign keys. Am I supposed to use foreign keys here? I understand that I'd have to add 2 foreign keys to AlbumsConnection, 1 for each table and each foreign key will reference to the primary keys ( which are the ids ) of the other 2 tables. Is that correct?

Comment: "Am I supposed to use foreign keys here?" Yes foreign keys enforce data integrity... "I understand that I'd have to add 2 foreign keys to AlbumsConnection, 1 for each table and each foreign key will reference to the primary keys ( which are the ids ) of the other 2 tables. Is that correct?"  Yes pretty much sounds correct... And make sure the tables are created with the InnoDB engine..... But question is mostly primarily opinion-based

Comment: What do you mean by ''And make sure the tables are created with the InnoDB engine'' ? I'm using phpMyAdmin to create my database and tables. Does it use that engine?

Comment: Only innoDB engine supports foreign keys. "Does it use that engine?" Don't know the defualt is set in the MySQL server but iám sure you can select the Innodb engine as option when creating the tables.

Comment: Ah yes, it uses InnoDB.

Comment: see Gordon Linoff's anwser it explains a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys help ensure relational integrity of the database.  There is no requirement for declaring them explicitly, but it is a good idea, particularly if you are learning to use databases.

The foreign key let's the database know that a column in one table is related to a column in another table.  I don't think MySQL's optimizer uses this information explicitly, although it does create an index on the foreign key column (unlike most other databases).

In addition, a declared foreign key relationship can help you deal with changes to the database.  It will prevent invalid albums from being inserted into the junction table.  If you delete an album, it gives you control over how the deletion and updating is handled (via `cascading` constraints).